# Unable to open Browser in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running simple code in selenium and it throws below exception:-

```
@Test
public void test(){

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "geckodriver.exe");   
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://google.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

Following error is shown when I have executed my script:

Previously it was working, my firefox version is 55 and i am using latest gecko driver version. Please help!!

> **Exception is:-**
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:136)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$000(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.usingFirefoxBinary(GeckoDriverService.java:108)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:204)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:103)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
>     at newTab.Tab.test(Tab.java:16)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)

Comment: It seems like you are copy this code from some where else and forget to replace the string from `webdriver.chrome.driver` to `webdriver.gecko.driver`

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong syntax near **"System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "geckodriver.exe");"**.  Replace **"chrome.driver"** with **"gecko.driver"**

```
@Test public void test(){
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "geckodriver.exe");       
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://google.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

Replace it with

```
@Test public void test(){
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://google.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

Comment: @iamasnkalp89:- oops my mistake i corrected my code to :-  '@Test
 public void test(){
  
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://google.com");
  driver.manage().window().maximize();

  
 }' but still it throws same error.

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
Exception is:- java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V at
```

is Java's way of telling you that your code is internally invoking a method called

```
void checkState(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)
```

within the class `com.google.common.base.Preconditions` but this method is not available.

This usually happens when your classpath is messed up.

You haven't mentioned what version of Selenium you are working with. So I am going to assume that you are working with the latest released version of Selenium viz., `3.5.2`.

Please make sure that you are using `com.google.guava:guava` version `23.0`.

If you are using Maven, then you can perhaps add a dependency which looks like below, to your pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: :- Thanks!! Yes i am using 3.5.2 selenium version and i also added above mentioned dependencies in my pom.xml but it still throws same error.

Comment: The order of the dependencies matter in maven. Please try adding this dependency as the first one. You can try running `mvn dependency:tree` to find out which of your dependencies is bringing in an older guava version and add exclusions accordingly

Answer (score 0):

it's conflict problem, you should check on Project Structure, if it exists 2 Maven, it's conflict problem, you have to delete "Maven: com.google.guava: guava:jdk...". If it exists only 1 Maven guava, just need update the dependency